# Prove that $P(\exists n\in N:S_n=n-2008)=1$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, martingales

Let $X_n$, $n=1,2,...$ be independent random variables. $P(X_n=1)=\frac{1}{2}=P(X_n=-1)$

$S_n=\sum_1^nX_k$, $T=inf[n:S_n=n-2008]$

a) Prove that $P(\exists n\in N:S_n=n-2008)=1$

b) Prove $ET\leq2008$

My attempt is obviously wrong, but let me show you.

$T$ is a stopping moment, ${n\wedge T}$ is also a stopping moment, S is a martingale

$$ES_{n\wedge T}=\Bbb E[S_T1_{\{T \le n\}}]+\Bbb E[S_n1_{T> n}]=0.$$

$$S_T=n-2008$$ which goes to infinity as n goes to infinity, so my result would be the opposite of thesis a), namely $P(T<\infty)=0$

EDIT:

my new idea is to form another variable $Z_n=S_n-n+2008$, this would be a supermartingale.

Comment: Hint for a): Totally elementary, can you reformulate the condition $S_n=n-2008$ considering how often $X_i=-1$ has happened for $i=1,\ldots,n$?

Comment: Ok, this would mean that -1 appears exactly 1004 times and there is Bernoulli distribution, which sums to 1.

Comment: Right, I think this does a) easily and should be a help for b) as well.